# cURL loading cross-domain remote XML - how to read & format it?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, curl

I'm using the following to load a remote XML file stored on a different server..

```
<?php $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pathtofile.com/data.xml");

$xml = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

And as you can see, the results are being stored in the $xml string.

I can display this in the broswer by using :

```
<?php echo $xml; ?>
```

But I need to select and format just certain parts of the data.

I know it can be done, and I've read tons of posts about how to do it via xmlhttp and many other ways, but I can't find a method specific to my needs as my XML file is now essentially a PHP string.

I'm after the same kind of functionality as the following JS Script (which would work just fine if the XML file was stored locally, but as mine isn't it doesn't work) :

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://pathtofile.com/data.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("event");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction or offer an example please? I'm just not sure how to call the $xml string for use in this way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use DOMDocument class, for parsing your XML string and getting the node values.

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Example #1 should work for you, for extracting events like this:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$events = $dom->getElementsByTagName('event');
$rows = '';
foreach ($events as $event) {
    $date = $name = '';
    foreach ($event->childNodes as $child) {
        switch ($child->nodeName) {
            case 'date':
                $date = $child->nodeValue;
            break;
            case 'name':
                $name = $child->nodeValue;
            break;
        }
    }
    $rows .= "<tr><td>${date}</td><td>${name}</td></tr>";
}

echo 'test'.$rows;

?>
```

The second solution would be XSL:

http://php.net/manual/en/xsl.examples-collection.php

Create the template for your needs and use XSLTPRocessor class.

http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.construct.php